# sql - Updating 2 columns from 2 select statment

Tags: sql, select, oracle10g, sql-update

How can i update 2 columns from field in another table?

in field `DOMAIN` on `TABLE2` i have this string:

```
;*.mydomain.co.il;
```

I  have extracted  the `mydomain.co.il`. now i want to:

1. Update the field `UR`L in `TABLE1`
2. Update the field `REDIRECT` in `TABLE1`

   ```
   UPDATE TABLE1
      set URL = (SELECT concat('http//', trim(both ';' from DOMAIN))
                  FROM TABLE2 
                 WHERE id = 99999
                )

          REDIRECT = (SELECT concat('http//', 
                                    trim(both ';' from  REGEXP_REPLACE(domain,
                                                                      'mydomain',
                                                                      'otherdomain'
                                                                       )
                                         )
                                   )
                        FROM TABLE2 
                       WHERE id = 88888

                     )
   ```

*ErrorMessage: ORA-00933; SQL command not properly ended*

ok. i updated my query and now i get this error:

```
[Oracle Data Provider for .NET] Number: 971
ErrorMessage: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
```

Why missing SET ?

```
UPDATE TABLE1 a, TABLE2 s
SET 
a.URL = concat('http//', trim(both ';' from s.DOMAIN), 
a.REDIRECT = concat('http//', trim(both ';' from  REGEXP_REPLACE(s.domain , 'mydomain', 'otherdomain'))
where s.id = 8888
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `,` between both settings :

```
UPDATE TABLE1
    SET URL = (SELECT CONCAT('http//', TRIM(BOTH ';' FROM DOMAIN))
            FROM TABLE2
            WHERE id = 99999),
        REDIRECT = ( SELECT CONCAT('http//', TRIM(BOTH ';' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(domain , 'mydomain' , 'otherdomain')))
            FROM TABLE2
            WHERE id = 88888)
```

Answer (score 1):

An updateable join view would do it, if you have a unique or primary key on id.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/views.htm#i1006232

Alternatively, a MERGE can update multiple columns based on a join.

Comment: 1. I prefer to keep it more simple. i have no idea how to do join view.

Comment: Have you read the documentation link? Update the question with your best effort so far and we'll see what's going wrong.